# How to remove text (name, address etc.) entries that were saved on pc from a search on a web site

Tags: windows-10

I sometimes fill a search box on a web site, the finish and close.
When returning to the same web site, my older text is shown as a possible entry.
How can I delete these entries?

e.g. the Travel Channel contest site does this. 
I'm OK with it for that but I want to delete items for other sites.
So far, unable to find if or where stored on my (WIN10) pc.

Ideas appreciated.

Comment: This should tell you what to do for whichever browser you are using: https://support.iclasspro.com/hc/en-us/articles/218569268-How-to-Disable-and-Clear-AutoFill-Info-in-your-Browser

Comment: IMHO, your question can't be answered, because every browser handles this differently. The link in the comment above gives many hints, but we still don't know if you use a browser which is covered there. Please note that neither a "site" nor Windows does store your entries; it is the browser which is doing it.